# Can you say "I am middle-paid" or "I am normal-paid" to mean you are paid an amount somewhere between the highest and lowest level?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

If someone ask you if you are paid well in your job, and you want to say you are not well-paid, but you are not badly-paid either. So, how do you say you are paid in the middle of the highest and lowest level? For instance;

**A: Are you well-paid?**

**B: No, I am normally paid/medium paid/middle paid.**

OR

**B: I am paid all right./OK.**

I know none of them seems idiomatic, but I can't be sure what would be an idiomatic answer to mean you are not well-paid, nor badly-paid, and are paid somewhere in the middle of the highest and lowest salary?

Comment: We would probably say "*averagely paid*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would probably say "*averagely paid*" if we thought our pay was somewhere in the middle of what is considered low and high pay. This would be relative to the context though - whether we were talking about the average pay within the organisation we worked for, the sector we worked in, or across a wider area such as our country or even the world.

You might also consider saying '*reasonably paid*', which suggests that we are neither *underpaid* nor *overpaid* for the work we do. This is more relative to what is considered reasonable or normal remuneration for the kind of work we do rather than what *is* paid, dictating mean averages. This term also better conveys that you are somewhat satisfied with the pay.

Comment: Perfect and complete explanation. I appreciate it. Thanks.